# How to correctly implement cohen kappa metric in keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, scikit-learn

I tried to implement cohen kappa metric for my project using custom metric guide provided by tensorflow for keras (https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/train_and_evaluate#custom_metrics).

After I trained my model and predicted output, I compared results with `sklearn.metrics.cohen_kappa_score` and it is not same. Can anyone tell how to resolve this problem? Here's the code:

```
class BinaryKappa(keras.metrics.Metric):
    """Stateful Metric to calculate kappa over all batches.
    Assumes predictions and targets of shape `(samples, 1)`.
    # Arguments
        name: String, name for the metric.
    """

    def __init__(self, name='glo_kappa', **kwargs):
        super(BinaryKappa, self).__init__(name=name, **kwargs)
        self.true_positives = self.add_weight(name='tp',initializer='zeros')
        self.true_negative = self.add_weight(name='tn',initializer='zeros')
        self.false_positives = self.add_weight(name='fp',initializer='zeros')
        self.false_negative = self.add_weight(name='fn',initializer='zeros')

    def reset_states(self):
        self.true_positives.assign(0.)
        self.true_negative.assign(0.)
        self.false_positives.assign(0.)
        self.false_negative.assign(0.)

    def update_state(self, y_true, y_pred, sample_weight=None):
        y_true = K.cast(y_true, 'int32')
        y_pred = K.cast(K.round(y_pred), 'int32')
        true_pos = K.cast(K.sum(y_pred * y_true),'int32')
        true_neg = K.cast(K.sum((1 - y_pred) * (1 - y_true)),'int32')
        false_pos = K.cast(K.sum(y_pred * (1 - y_true)),'int32')
        false_neg = K.cast(K.sum((1 - y_pred) * y_true),'int32')

        true_pos = K.cast(true_pos, "float32")
        true_neg = K.cast(true_neg, "float32")
        false_pos = K.cast(false_pos, "float32")
        false_neg = K.cast(false_neg, "float32")

        self.true_positives.assign_add(true_pos)
        self.true_negative.assign_add(true_neg)
        self.false_positives.assign_add(false_pos)
        self.false_negative.assign_add(false_neg)

    def result(self):
        sm = self.true_positives + self.true_negative + self.false_positives + self.false_negative
        obs_agree = (self.true_positives + self.true_negative) / sm
        poss_pos = (self.true_positives + self.false_negative) * (self.true_positives + self.false_positives) / (sm**2)
        poss_neg = (self.true_negative + self.false_negative) * (self.true_negative + self.false_positives) / (sm**2)
        poss_agree = poss_pos + poss_neg
        return (obs_agree - poss_agree) / (1 - poss_agree + K.epsilon())
```

Answer (score 1):

The metric is discrete so you need an approximation. But,

have a look at `tf.contrib`, which implements `cohen_kappa`.

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/23c218785eac5bfe737eec4f8081fd0ef8e0684d/tensorflow/contrib/metrics/python/ops/metric_ops.py#L3595

or even better have a look at the metric's implementation at kaggle.com

https://www.kaggle.com/christofhenkel/weighted-kappa-loss-for-keras-tensorflow

Answer (score 0):

Do this with information from confuse_matrix and do not pay attention to
some other sklearn library.

[image]
    from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

```
NBC = NBC.fit(X_train,y_train)
cm = confusion_matrix(y_test, NBC.predict(X_test))
tn, fp, fn, tp = cm.ravel()
print('tn: ',tn)
print('fp: ',fp)
print('fn: ',fn)
print('tp: ',tp)
print('------------------')
print(cm) 

p_0 = (tn+)/(tn+fp+fn+)
print('p_0:',p_0)

P_a = ((tn+fp)/(tn+fp+fn+))*((tn+fn)/(tn+fp+fn+))
print('P_yes: ',P_yes)

P_b = ((fn+)/(tn+fp+fn+))*((fp+)/(tn+fp+fn+))
print('P_no: ',P_no)


pe = P_a + P_b
print('pe: ',pe)

κ = (p_0-pe)/(1-pe)
print('κ: ',κ)
```